# file upload system

Tags: php

Does anyone know of the file upload system which I can use for my application which is either open source or can be purchased?

I need to be able to upload file/s to the web server and send out email links to users to download the files?

I really need this to be an 'all in one' solution where I can just install/setup as i'm not really a developer!

a bit like http://www.yousendit.com/

Don't mind which language any is fine.

Answer (score 2):

S3 is an API to a storage cloud, it doesn't really have an interface like yousendit.com.  You'd need to do a bit of programming to get it to work for you.

There's a whole stack of possible apps [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/upload-systems/) but i haven't personally tried any of them.

Also, if this is going to  turn into a "how to build/use this php app", I think I'd suggest migration to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

[UploadScript](http://uploadscript.com) is exactly what you are after. It is a file upload system written in PHP which you can easily add to your website. You can upload multiple files at the time and then simply send out links to each file to whoever you want.